# Convert each row of dataframe to new list in R

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I have below sample `input` data-

```
> df <- data.frame(a=c(1,2,9),b=c(3,4,5),c=c(2,6,7))
> df
  a b c
1 1 3 2
2 2 4 6
3 9 5 7
```

I am trying to convert rach `row` into separate list.

**My Attempt-**

```
> apply(df,1,as.list)
```

The above solution converts each `row` into `sublists`. But, I am looking for 3 separate list in this case.

`nrow(df) = no. of lists`

**Desired Output-**

```
> list1
$a
[1] 1

$b
[1] 3

$c
[1] 2

> list2
$a
[1] 2

$b
[1] 4

$c
[1] 6

> list3
$a
[1] 9

$b
[1] 5

$c
[1] 7
```

Comment: Do you need `split(df, 1:nrow(df))` ?

Comment: What does "independent list" mean exactly? What's the desired output here?

Comment: I have added my desired output. Independent means, all three separate lists. `nrow(df) = no. of lists`

Comment: `lapply(split(df, 1:nrow(df)), as.list)` -> how about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `by` and `as.list`

```
out <- by(df, 1:nrow(df), as.list)
out
#1:nrow(df): 1
#$a
#[1] 1
#
#$b
#[1] 3

#$c
#[1] 2

#------------------------------------------------------------------------------ 
#1:nrow(df): 2
#$a
#[1] 2

#$b
#[1] 4

#$c
#[1] 6

#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#1:nrow(df): 3
#$a
#[1] 9

#$b
#[1] 5

#$c
#[1] 7
```

That creates an object of class `by`. So you may call `unclass(out)` in the end.